# Why is there a need for MODE_PRIVATE in openFileOutput?

Tags: java, android, file

I read the docs for openFileOutput and saw that "Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist"(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

For the second parameter, you have to specify a mode. Wouldn't specifying MODE_PRIVATE be redundant and unnecessary because a private file can only be opened by the application that called for it?

Comment: simply for security. Avoid someone editing your data without your permission

Comment: The file being private already adds security though. MODE_PRIVATE doesn't really do anything

Comment: Advice on how i can word this question better? I thought this one was pretty clear, just asking if MODE_PRIVATE was redundant or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mode` argument is a bitfield. You can use bitwise or to pass more than one `MODE_` flag to the open function.

The value of `MODE_PRIVATE` is `0` i.e. no bits are set. By default files are private and you need to explicitly set other flags there to grant additional filesystem level permissions, or to control file opening mode (append/overwrite).

Sure, there *could* be an overload without any mode bits i.e. `openFileOutput(String)` but there isn't. Writing the `, 0` does not take too many keystrokes.

Comment: I get the append/overwrite and the need to have another mode value for that why need MODE_PRIVATE when you know the file you're getting back is private?

Comment: You can leave the mode as 0 to get the default of `MODE_PRIVATE`.

Comment: I get that. I just feel its redundant to even 0 as an option